# uniform convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{\alpha}e^{-nt^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider for $\alpha >0$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{\alpha}e^{-nt^2}$

a) Prove that for $\alpha >2$ the series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.
b) Prove that for $0<\alpha\leq 2$, the series doesn't converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

The supremum is at $t=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2n}}$. 
Therefore you get that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{\alpha}e^{-nt^2}<\sum\frac{\alpha^{\alpha/2}}{2n^{\alpha/2}}e^{-nt^2}=0$ if $\alpha>2$.

How would I prove b) ?

Comment: Something isn't right - the expression you posted is equal to $$\frac{t^{\alpha}}{e^{t^2}-1}$$

Comment: Following @rlgordonma, the error incurred by dropping summands with $n> N$ is $\frac{t^\alpha}{e^{t^2}-1}\cdot e^{-Nt^2}$, which is bounded as $t\to\infty$, but as $t\to 0$, it is $\sim t^{\alpha-2}$. Hence the behaviour changes at $\alpha=2$ and notat $\alpha=\frac12$.

Comment: @julien: Sorry, of course, I don't know what I was thinking... Will delete comment.

Comment: Sorry guys, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha\geq 0$.

You have perfectly observed the uniform convergence on $[0,+\infty)$ when $\alpha>2$.

Assume that the convergence is uniform on $[0,+\infty)$.
Then the sum
$$
f(t)=\frac{t^\alpha}{e^{t^2}-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}t^\alpha e^{-nt^2}
$$
is continuous as a uniform limit of continuous function. Note that 
$$
f(t)\sim \frac{t^\alpha}{t^2}=t^{\alpha-2}
$$
at $0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, this forces $\alpha\geq 2$.

So it only remains to consider the case $\alpha=2$. Denote $S_N$ the partial sums of $f$. Then we have
$$
f(t)-S_{N-1}(t)=\sum_{n\geq N}t^2e^{-nt^2}
$$
In particular, for $t_N=\sqrt{1/N}$, we get
$$
\|f-S_{N-1}\|_\infty\geq \sum_{n\geq N}\frac{e^{-n/N}}{N}=\frac{e^{-1}}{N(1-e^{-1/N})}\sim\frac{e^{-1}}{N\frac{1}{N}}=e^{-1}.$$
So the partial sums do not converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,+\infty)$.

**Conclusion:** there is uniform convergence on $[0,+\infty)$ if and only if $\alpha>2$.

Comment: @Kasper Please take a look at my answer and tell me what you think.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I guess I missed your comment. I like your explanation :)

Comment: @Kasper I had completely forgotten about that answer myself...Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f_n(t)=t^\alpha e^{-nt^2}.$$
The supremum of is attained at $t_n=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2n}}$ then since
$$||f_n||_\infty=\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)^\alpha\frac{e^{-\alpha/2}}{n^{\alpha/2}},$$
we have the normal convergence of the series $\sum_n f_n(t)$ which implies the uniform convergence for $\alpha>2$ by comparaison with the Riemann series .

Now, suppose $0<\alpha\leq2$. We have the uniform convergence of the series if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{t\in[0,\infty)}|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(t)|=0.$$

We have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{t\in[0,\infty)}|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(t)|\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(t_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)^\alpha\frac{e^{-\alpha/2}}{k^{\alpha/2}}=+\infty,$$
indeed, the last equality comes from
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{\alpha/2}}\geq\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha/2}}=\int_n^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha/2}}=+\infty$$
since $0<\alpha\leq2$.

Comment: How do you pass from $t$ to multiple $t_k$'s? In other words, how do you justify the first $\geq$? I might be blind but I can't see it.

Comment: Simply, the supremum of function is always great or equal a value of the function at a point or several points.

Comment: This argument does not work. The first inequality $\geq$ is not true. Take $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=(1-t)^2$ on $[0,1]$. Then $\sup f(t)=1=\sup g(t)$, but $\sup (f+g)(t)=1<1+1=2$.

Comment: You're right, I'll think about it. Thank for the comment.